# Opening WinForm according to computer time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have a project working for my clients, now I am trying to make my licencing system more advanced and I want to add one check in software.
The thing is that I want when my client is working on my software and computer clock shows some time `(e.g. 12:00)` I want to open one of `WinForms` for checking online licence that user have.
I thought this could be very easy to make, but since I don't want to use `Timers` inside my code and make my software work slower I am now kind a stack into my own code.

This is what I've tried for now:

```
    Dim day As String = Format(Today, "dddd")
    Dim time As Date
    Dim CurrHour As Integer
    Dim CurrMinute As Integer
    Dim CurrSecond As Integer
    time = My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime 'Ive tried to use DateTime.Now here
    CurrHour = time.Hour ' Get current hour value
    CurrMinute = time.Minute ' Get current minute value
    CurrSecond = time.Second ' Get current second value
    If CurrHour = 12 AndAlso CurrMinute = 0 AndAlso CurrSecond = 30 Then
        MsgBox("12 hours 0 minutes 30 seconds")
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there any other way except using `Timer.Tick` for this to make it working?

Comment: you need timer to do that, if you afraid from your app become slower then use it as standalone service to check the licence. Also when you use service you don't need your app to be working at that time because if it close it will not tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a Timer? You can set it the interval to several hours and it only ticks once.

When a timespan there should be no problem ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Sorry but your answer did not help he want a way without using timer, and you provide reference in `German`

Comment: Of course he should use a Timer.  Not using one is just plain dumb, as silly as downvoting this perfectly good answer.

Comment: Using a seperate service for what a simple timer can do (and I see no perfomance problem with a timer that ticks only once) is like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Thanks for fixing the link Hans :)

Comment: Well I was thinking about seting Timer interval to tick ever 30 minutes or 1 hour. But I thought then since Timer is active (but without ticking) that he will also take more resources... Seems like I've made a mistake...
@DavidSdot thank you for your reference.